# 1997 Toyota Corolla, Hot Air Blowing into Cabin (non-AC model)

Tags: toyota, corolla, hvac, cabin

We have a base model (no AC, no options) manual 1997 Toyota Corolla that we are trying to keep alive long enough to teach the kids how to drive with a clutch.

Whenever there is airflow into the cabin (passive or with fan on), the air is hot. I'm assuming this is engine heat, and perhaps some baffle that is supposed to direct the air on a non-heated path has failed.

Are there any other likely explanations? And either way, what are some fixes I may be able to attempt?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest sounds correct.

The ventilation system will have a flap that controls the amount of warm and cold air entering the passenger compartment.

Possible faults I can think of -

- The heating system temperature sensor is faulty, so it always thinks
  it is too cold in the passenger compartment.
- The temperature control is broken so it thinks more heat has been
  requested.
- The flap is physically stuck in the hot position.
- The actuator is broken that controls the flap.
- There is a broken connection to the actuator.
- The heating computer is faulty

Comment: With a car this basic, I believe you've pointed me to it I believe this car is pure analog, possibly without even a cabin air temp sensor. Likely a cable running from the control lever to the actuator for a flap. Will start there next weekend. Thank you!